# storing normal class in Platform:Collections:Vector

Tags: uwp, c++-cx

Hello, i'm trying to do some basic UWP application as part of my school project. I would like to store instances of my normal class Student

```
class Student
{
public:
    wstring Name;
    wstring SuName;
    int StudentId;
    Student(wstring Name,wstring SuName,int StudentId);
    ~Student();
};
```

in Vector so i can bind it to the ListView

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();  
    Student *a = new Student(L"bbb", L"bbb", 1);
    Student *b = new Student(L"ccc", L"ccc", 2);
    Platform::Collections::Vector<Student*, std::equal_to <Student*>>^ LoS = 
    ref new Vector<Student*,std::equal_to <Student*>>();
    LoS->Append(a);
    LoS->Append(b);
    List->ItemsSource = LoS;
}
```

sadly Platform:Collections:Vector only accepts ref and scalar types, is there any way of storing instances of normal class in the Platform:Collections:Vector ? i've done quite extensive research but i haven't found real answer, only some mentions of making custom function objects, but i have no idea how to make those. As a side note, the class student has to be normal class, i can't change it to ref class

Comment: "the class student has to be normal class" why? According to official blog https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2013/07/30/new-features-in-ccxs-collection-h-for-vs-2013-rtm/ the collection will check whether you are writing the supported type. You cannot use types that are not supported in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind to the XAML UI, you need to use a `ref` class. If you *cannot* change the definition of `Student` then one solution is to provide a simple wrapper.

#### Header file for your page

```
namespace WhateverYourNamespaceIs
{
  // Simplified version of your class...
  class Student
  {
  public:
    std::wstring Name;
    Student(const std::wstring& name) : Name(name) {}
  };

  // Bindable ref wrapper
  [Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
  public ref class StudentWrapper sealed
  {
  // "internal" means "public to C++ but hidden from WinRT clients."
  // It is *required* in order to use normal C++ classes.
  internal:
    Student student;
    StudentWrapper(const Student& student) : student(student) {}

  public:
    property Platform::String^ Name 
    { 
      Platform::String^ get() 
      { 
        return ref new Platform::String(student.Name.data()); 
      }
    }
  };

  // Your normal MainPage class
  public ref class MainPage sealed
  {
  public:
    MainPage();
  };
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

#### XAML for your page:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <ListView x:Name="students" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
</Grid>
```

#### Implementation for your page:

```
MainPage::MainPage()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  auto vec = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<StudentWrapper^>();
  vec->Append(ref new StudentWrapper(Student(L"Alice")));
  vec->Append(ref new StudentWrapper(Student(L"Bob")));
  vec->Append(ref new StudentWrapper(Student(L"Chris")));

  students->ItemsSource = vec;
}
```